# selecionar e contar checkbox

Tags: javascript

Não consigo acertar o codigo abaixo: a variavel total não soma em countCheckedCheckboxes.
E quando clica no botão marca todos porem se desmarcar alguns e clicar no botão novamente o que estava marcado desceleciona e o que estava descelecionado fica marcado.

SCRIPT

```
var total=0;
function checkAll(theForm, cName) {
    for (i=0,n=theForm.elements.length;i<n;i++){
        if (theForm.elements[i].className.indexOf(cName) !=-1)
            theForm.elements[i].checked = !(theForm.elements[i].checked);   
     }
        total = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    var $checkboxes = $('#checkbox_form td input[type="checkbox"]');

    $checkboxes.change(function(){   
        var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
        countCheckedCheckboxes=(countCheckedCheckboxes+total);

        $('#count-checked-checkboxes').text(countCheckedCheckboxes);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consegui meu intento e vou compartilhar o codigo:

```
var w=0;
var y=0;
function checkAll(theForm, cName, status) {

for (i=0,n=theForm.elements.length;i<n;i++)
    if (theForm.elements[i].className.indexOf(cName) !=-1) {
      theForm.elements[i].checked = status;
    }
}

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $checkboxes = $('#checkbox_form td input[type="checkbox"]');
        $checkboxes.change(function(){   

        var meu_array = ['RIhBx','ddwkj','qmCvU','IFRtS','KiLNX','cmSEL','cAFUq','PJkBz','cEpFF','NZJhD','UfVPS','lrvnJ','ftfte','IJFNS'];

        for ( var i = 0; i < meu_array.length; i++ ) {

                $("input:checkbox[class="+meu_array[ i ]+"]").each(function () {
                    if($(this).is(":checked")==true){
                        w=1;
                    }else{
                        y=1;
                    }
                }); 

            if ((w==0) && (y==1)){
                document.getElementById(meu_array[ i ]).checked = false;
            }
            w=0;
        }   

        var tot=$('input[name="songs[]"]:checked').length;
        if (tot==0){
            $('#count-checked-checkboxes').text("");
        }else if (tot==1){
            $('#count-checked-checkboxes').text(tot+" selecionada");
        }else{
            $('#count-checked-checkboxes').text(tot+" selecionadas");
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que isto te Ajuda Léo.
Usei Jquery pois vi que voce fez o uso e separei os checkbox por CSS class, pois pode ser que queira selecionar e verificar um determinado conjunto de checkbox.

```js
$("#btnAll").click(function(){
       // $(":checkbox") Poderia usar este tbm .. só que irá pegar todos os checkbox do seu document
       $(".carro").prop( "checked", true);
       countCarroSelecionados();
});

$("#btnClear").click(function(){
       // $(":checkbox") Poderia usar este tbm .. só que irá pegar todos os checkbox do seu document
       $(".carro").prop( "checked", false);
       countCarroSelecionados();
});

$("#btnShowResult").click(function(){
       countCarroSelecionados();
});

function countCarroSelecionados(){
 var checkBoxs =  $( ".carro" ).filter(function() {
    return $(this).prop('checked');
   });
  alert(checkBoxs.length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="">
<button id="btnAll" type="button">
  Selecionar Todos
</button>
<button type="button" id="btnClear">
  Limpar
</button>
<button type="button" id="btnShowResult">
  Resultado
</button>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="carro" value="mustang">Mustang
  <input type="checkbox" class="carro" value="camaro">Camaro
  <input type="checkbox" class="carro" value="veloster">Veloster
  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mas são varios grupos e cada um com uma  classe. São trezentas classes

Comment: neste exemplo o desenvolvedor também utilizou class. Voce pode colocar eles dentro de uma div e pra cada div percorrer o DOM p/ ver se há checkbox p/ marcar. Mas vejo que a sua necessidade realmente vai ter trabalho pra separar os grupos de checkbox.